# Have an requirement to verify the input (from eventhub) of stream analytics jobs for data quality

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-stream-analytics, data-quality

Is there a way to detect data quality issues from the streaming inputs (eventhub) (JSON) in Azure stream analytics?

**Scenarios:**
1) Bad messages: Blank records, NULLS/Spaces in key columns
2) values above expected Range, incorrect data type etc.
3) Non- Standard messages

Have checked Anomaly detection but it does not provide these features.

NOTE: I am running a job  for =Data Quality in parallel to data processing to capture messages with data quality issues into BLOB to investigate/reprocess.

To avoid the performance issues in processing pipeline.

Has anyone implemented a data Quality framework in Azure ?

Thanks,
Mohan

Comment: You will have to code that out and I don't think ASA is the best tool to do that. I'd say do it in the processing pipeline. Anomaly Detection is something entirely different: it detects anomalies in the data stream itself, like fast raising temperatures or spikes in outages for example.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Doing those checks in processing pipeline will it not impact performance? Also will java script udf  of stream analytics provided by azure be  a right candidate for doing that ?

Comment: We also do not have access to perform those logics in the source systems directly.

Comment: I don't think it will have any more impact doing it in the processing pipeline than it does using a js udf in stream analytics. How many message per second are we talking about anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Using Azure Stream Analytics, you can add different filters to check if the messages are compliant to your business logic:

- Add filters in the WHERE clause for detecting: blank records, NULLS/Spaces in key columns, and values above expected ranges
- Use TRY_CAST feature to detect incorrect data types

However, Azure Stream Analytics will rely on well formatted messages, so won't be able to read messages that are not valid JSON. So it will probably not fulfil all your requirements.